# how to set labels in gauge (echarts)

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts, ngx-echarts

I want to set labels dynamically for the gauge chart as per screenshot.
[requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUrtH.png)

challenges:

1. dynamic markpoint with icon.
2. main label of gauge with icon and css.

my original gauge chart is
[gauge config link](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-y-category-stack&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeBYAULTsBEBzAThACbYBcy6WVOAxjGAIYTQAyDARgKYA2ZsY-AK6cANJWqZsYUHwCMADjEYJOdsDDSAtnwBMABiUqc3TgDMwcg-InZCuABYXyAZj3XYAX0NZsJ3J2gSclRlGwBne2AAdz4BYW8bMABPEE4-bDCafGBuXgTqbDUNYG1yK1CChm4IXGh0u0dsdy93KWAcyBA-EKMpO398dIgwTm18qmwGAA8IMIAFYGYRweD3XuTU9KzgMLDscZVfDh5utaMfdgYaAGsCYEFAgGEc4BWcAGIANgYAdgBOeQAViaFSMHjOmBaoJ8plemgYGk4b2wSHYHlgwRoHhBVChEzo3FefAA2hCPgAWR5_ACCADFaTisABdfIZJEQTh7cik6GYHrnSQbNLkPAMQT-fZkib4BhECCCLk4WR6PQAUklvMqMzCLGYwoomt61WgnAAyskTKdDQLaC83jybY7YA6na69AA6QEHV29d70wGfVyMn0qFlSn0ukMCj0_b1RiZ-2nUgBCKuD8eZcZDkYzElkWYz2Hezk-yecPwAounc0zwwKw9aBdgosQwPY5IC69RwY3PAXJEQEQwSV2qPz49hoAxNPrsAB5ABuSKq3FgADk5qaNbnsAuqsI-J9Pu7Pj9R1ge46G47sJpmHwALTK8o3-FTSwvm1SYaW1a9iYRNEsRCKI56SMApimGEnBgI8ATLCO_4qJ-E6Ajo6pgbA14-tgBJEiK7w6BWzjyOSAAi244bC0BgKaEAAF76rI5L9gU1FgAA6pwNSNCKajcEQSLVioeJfmEjD4GA1LQLgv44PoeiUU2ARENJsmzg--hKeckzagAKhANxWiGGSRDE5CmFU0GsQBIDVGAa6CJoXBvLIXaiU2YR2cMuomsZOEmDJba6ChTrYHK4kMNAND6k-XqYb4ermkkcnjlGzatu25A6DZhx4ci7yPEVxXCQKl42h5OmCYwEC8H-Jmwvg8KIm8R4nrGCX5ekhHEaRFG5ZI7F0YxcgsQl7FcTxTiqDkgmDANOAQVBMFwTRQncphVChSZrgYUhmC1r2lW9MMozJalnV2t1xUle5rG6bMbBcHVBomRFjDRfqOg5ZdhLIsw9jshYd1dtgICLGtbxpTegW4MFIo_Gq2k3i2RDw7Anwg728L4NcCxLPVTphEkzk5OQADkNAQPgNAmOTuWDowG37WOm2wFOM4U5k-CcAE9OYXu3DCOQnzbTaUwiyqC1JOQsiAm4FTlQdWM3jFkOISZ8vqgt2Ci3tV5kkrWHoB4QA)

I tried using markpoint but unable to find coordinates dynamically.

Thanks in advance.